# PNG sprite sheets in SVG graphics

Tags: svg

I have this PNG file with regularly spaced sprites and I'd like to use it in my web application that uses SVG for visualizations. Of course, I could overlay the SVG document with floating  elements and do the ol-good

```
<img style="width: 32px; height: 32px; background: url(sprites.png) 0 0;"/>
```

But that would be messy to handle both SVG and HTML overlays separately.

What would be the SVG markup to use the same png spritesheet to display raster icons in the SVG document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example that demonstrates how to apply SVG clipping to a PNG image to crop it to show only the selected frame: http://jsfiddle.net/passiday/trke6nou/

```
// See the Sprite class in JSFiddle
var bird = new Sprite({
  stage      : "stage",
  id         : "bird",
  href       : "http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/1406635974jay.png",
  imageWidth : 329,
  imageHeight: 300,
  frames     : 8,
  tileCols   : 3,
  tileWidth  : 110,
  tileHeight : 100
});
bird.set(frame, x, y);
```